# Stored procedure not returning results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I wrote a stored procedure but this is not return any results. The query of the procedure work normally. But same query not return any result in the procedure.

Procedure:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[GetValuesByDateRange](@dateFrom as datetime2, @dateTo as datetime2, @devId as varchar)
as
select *
from SensorValues
where AddDate between @dateFrom and @dateTo
and JSON_VALUE(Value,'$.DevId') = @devId
```

Query

```
select *
from SensorValues
where AddDate
between '2020-12-10 00:00:00' and '2020-12-14 00:00:00'
and JSON_VALUE(Value,'$.DevId') = '408414743'
```

[image]

Comment: `varchar` must always have a length... else its `varchar(1)` which truncates your value. You need at least `varchar(9)` for your sample data probably longer.

Comment: Yes I forgot it unfortunately, it works now, thank you :)

Comment: What are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use **Parenthesis** between 2 Separate Conditions & also use varchar(max) instead of single varchar

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[GetValuesByDateRange](@dateFrom as datetime2, @dateTo as datetime2, 
@devId as varchar(9))
as
select * from SensorValues 
where (AddDate between @dateFrom and @dateTo)
and JSON_VALUE(Value,'$.DevId')= @devId
```

Comment: How would that make any difference? Parenthesis make no difference whatsoever! And better to choose an appropriate length than use `max`.

Comment: @DaleK- VARCHAR(MAX) Should occupy only required memory only rite? Instead of occupying 8000 bytes

Comment: Adding unnecessary parenthesis in this instance is confusing.

Comment: Using `VARCHAR(MAX)` indicates that any length string is valid - which is extremely unlikely. Far better to use meaningful values.